# Trying to learn the history of Objective-C, what is the message passing equivalent of "region.span.latitudeDelta /= 2.0;"?

Tags: objective-c

What is the message passing equivalent of:

```
region.span.latitudeDelta /= 2.0;
```

Comment: `region.span.latitudeDelta /= 2.0;` <=> `region.span.latitudeDelta = region.span.latitudeDelta/2.0;` It's from C. It's not proper to Objective-C. C, C++ used them too, and some other should also. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest to split it up.

```
id span = [region span];
CGFloat latitudeDelta = [span latitudeDelta] / 2.0;
[span setLatitudeDelta:latitudeDelta];
```

Now, to write as a single statement, replace the left-hand side with the right-hand side whenever the left-hand side appears in a later statement.

```
CGFloat latitudeDelta = [[region span] latitudeDelta] / 2.0;
[[region span] setLatitudeDelta:latitudeDelta];
```

And then

```
[[region span] setLatitudeDelta:[[region span] latitudeDelta] / 2.0];
```

Comment: Yey... I only managed to forget one [ ] and got it wrong. I'm on the right track now!